# Using Flyway for two databases, but only one at a time

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway, cockroachdb

I'm testing out PostgreSQL and CockroachDB with my application. I've got it such that I can run my application with either PostgreSQL OR CockroachDB. Is it possible to set Flyway up such that I can run either with Flyway support without errors occurring from also having it configured for the other database I'm not using at the moment?

I've tried looking for documentation that answers this, but it seems that most documentation in this area pertains to running both databases concurrently, which isn't what I'm trying to do here.

Not a huge deal, but I am curious... Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can't you create a .conf for each database type?

Comment: You can set spring.flyway.locations or spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix in your application yaml to specify what migrations to run. You can change these values during runtime for example.

Comment: @pringi that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of Flyway uses the config file. Issuing a command like [flyway migrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/migrate) will go to the configured database with the designated locations (folders where the migrations are stored).
So, to be able to switch on the fly, you have two choices. You can create two config files and then set them on execute from the command line, or, take direct control of the [configuration settings](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/) through the command line. So, two different command lines with the appropriate settings for where the migrations are stored and how to connect to them should let you do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Specifying the filesystem locations made this a breeze.